# What is wrong with my Bootstrap data-toggle implementation?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to implement a data toggle using bootstrap 4.2.1. Following the documentation, I came up with the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bottom-section position-relative">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link nav-team active text-center" id="team-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#team" aria-controls="team" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link nav-individual text-center" id="individual-tab" data-toggl="tab" data-target="#individual" aria-controls="individual" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Individual</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="bottom-section-content col-sm-12">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="team" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="team-tab"><p>asd</p></div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="individual" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="individual-tab"><p>sad</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I cant't figure out what is wrong, it should be working like this. Am I missing something with the bootstrap js?

Comment: In the `individual-tab` you wrote `data-toggl` instead of `data-toggle`. Fix the typo and see if it's still not working.

Comment: @elveti thanks. fixed, but still not working

Comment: As we can't see the <head> of your HTML, just to be sure, do you load all required JS files : bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js ? Plus, can you share more about what you want exactly to achieve ? And what problem is showing up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and found that if you are using 4.1.3, this implementation will not work with your current HTML. You have to upgrade your JS to Bootstrap 4.2.1.

Use: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Also @elveti is right you misspelled `data-toggle`.

Working Example using (4.2.1): https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/zeNVxo